# How can I auto sort integer field in Pyqt5 table?

Tags: pyqt5

I have a table with id and this ids start from 1 to 22. When I sort with following code:

```
a = QSortFilterProxyModel()
a.setSourceModel(model)
self.table_view = QTableView()
self.table_view.setModel(a)
self.table_view.setSortingEnabled(True)
self.table_view.sortByColumn(1, Qt.DescendingOrder)
```

It sorting as in the picture because 8 is bigger than 6 and 2 it reads as string but the column is integer.

[image: Sorting Example]

How can I sort the column as integer?

Comment: Or subclass the sort-proxy and reimplement [lessThan](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan). This will allow you to customise the sorting conditions exactly as you want. For a simple integer numeric sort, you can just convert the two values using `int` (with appropriate error-handling) and compare them using `<`.

Comment: @ekhumoro it makes sense and I kind of understand but I don't know how to implement in python

Comment: @MuratDemir There are lots of examples on SO, if you take the trouble to search (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22904080/984421)).